# How can I stop or interrupt an accidental gnu screen paste "ctrl-a ]"

Tags: gnu-screen, byobu

I am using gnu screen (byobu really but it seems the keybinding was from screen) and was trying to enter scrollback mode with "ctrl-a [" but I accidentally did "ctrl-a ]" which started pasting and apparently I had copied something with many 1000s of lines and it's been pasting for the last 15 minutes and nothing I have tried will stop it. I really don't want to fully kill byobu/screen overall because I need some of the screens to keep running.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like one possibility is "Ctrl-a k" which kills just the one window. It would be cool if there was a way to just cancel the paste but this way worked without killing everything.